# jQuery function not able to get values unless an alert is written

Tags: jquery

I have

```
   $j("input[id^='tab_name_edit']").each(function(){

    var divcnt = $j(this).attr('id');

    var divcnt = divcnt.split(/[_]/);
    nosoftabs = divcnt[divcnt.length-1];


        var tabnm1 = $j(this).val();
        addInputGroup(tabnm1);
        automateDynamicFields(nosoftabs);


    });


function automateDynamicFields(nosoftabs){
    //alert('No the value of nosoftab is recieved and the function works perfectly.')
    $j("input[id^='registration_label"+nosoftabs+"']").slice(0,-1).each(function(){
            add_tier($j('#dynamic_registration_url'+nosoftabs),'dynamic_registration_label',dynamic_registration_url_hn,nosoftabs);
        });
}
```

### What I have.

A function calling another function and passing a value `nosoftabs`. This value is recieved and the `function automateDynamicFields` works perfectly when i write Alert in it.

I know this has to do something with DOM elements not being ready. Is there any way to check if a `variable` is loaded in jQuery. I know using `$('myDiv').load(....)` this may be fixed, but curious to know if it can be done while putting a check on the variable load and only when it loads, it should be passed to the next function.

Comment: You need delete the `alert(...)` only, not the `$j...`.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues I am sorry I didn't get you. But I have tried running with and without any alert statement.

Comment: are you doing this inside of $(document).ready()? If not, do that.

Comment: yes, its inside  $(document).ready()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var abd = addInputGroup(tabnm1);


        if(abd.length>0){
            automateDynamicFields(nosoftabs);
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(function(){

                automateDynamicFields(nosoftabs);
            },800);

        }
```

and make addInputGroup return somthing.

Comment: change 800 to suits your dom wait. Anyways 800 may be enough since you get an alert and then things work out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dom issue, you can always put your script at the end of the html, that way the dom is loaded by the time the js runs...